# Lambdas and Runnable

Tags: java, lambda

My Understanding was Lambda's expression is used to replace boiler-plater code around an abstract implementation. 
So if i have to create a new Thread which takes a Runnable interface (Functional), 
i do not have to create a new Anonymous class, then provide void run() and then write my logic inside it
rather can simply use a lambda and point it to a method provided the method signature is same as run i.e. takes nothing, returns nothing.

However i could not understand the implementation below

```
Thread t= new Thread(()->printStudent(stud));

public static void printStudent(Student stud) {
        System.out.println("Student is "+ stud);
    }
```

In above case printStudent takes an argument (not like run() method of runnable) though somehow it works.

How does this work ?

Comment: The `stud` variable is defined in the enclosing scope. The value of that variable is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Because lamdba is not like anonymous classes, its `this` refers to `this` of the external class. Similarly is done with method references in java streams.

Comment: how did you do it with anonymous classes?

Answer (score 1):

The following code (wrapping/modifying your code in a class):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String item = "Hello, World!"
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> printItem(item));
        t.start();
    }

    public static void printItem(Object item) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String item = "Hello, World!"
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                printItem(item);
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void printItem(Object item) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Notice that in the first example you have to use a lambda (`->`). You wouldn't be able to use a method reference, however, as the method `printItem` does not match the signature of a `Runnable`. This would be illegal:

```
Thread t = new Thread(Main::printItem);
```

Basically, the method reference is the same as:

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        printItem(); // wouldn't compile because the method has parameters
    }
}
```

The expression after the `->`, or the code inside a `-> {}` block, is the same code that you would have put inside the `run()` method.

```
Runnable singleExpression = () -> /* this is the code inside run()*/;
Runnable codeBlock = () -> {
    // this is the code inside run()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the parameter to the `run()` method, it's the `() ->` part that represents the `run()`method. What you're doing it simply defining the method as:

```
 @Override
 public void run(){
      printStudent(stud); //the value of stud from the context copied here
 }
```

Comment: So are we saying that internally java would create an anonymous class which would have Student as instance variable and the same is enriched with whatever we pass it ?

Comment: I would not say exactly that. They differ in the way they're converted to bytecode, i.e the runtime behavior. Simply put, anonymous classes are instantiated and loaded *as a class* for each reference to them while lambda expressions are *invokedynamically* (that's a JVM instruction) inside what's called a Functional Interface.